# What is the limit of the following function, as $x$ approaches $1$?

Tags: limits

$$
\lim_{x \to {1}} \frac{\ln(x)}{\arctan(1-x)}.
$$
I tried solving this limit using the L'Hopital rule, and got the result $-1$. Somehow my gut tells me that this is not correct, so I wanted to ask here. For the first derivative I got
$$
\frac{1/x}{-1/(1+x^2)},
$$
and applying the limit I got $\frac{1}{-1}=-1$.

Comment: I think you are correct.

Comment: You can also use Taylor approximation about $x=1$: $$
\ln (x) = \ln (1 - (1 - x)) =  - (1 - x) +  \mathcal{O}((1 - x)^2 )
$$ and $$
\arctan (1 - x) = (1 - x) + \mathcal{O}((1 - x)^3 ).
$$ It will give you $-1$ as well.

Comment: The expression you mention however does not give $-1$ , if we insert $1$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct in solving this problem by using L'Hôpital's rule. The answer -1 is also correct

Solution:
$$\lim _{x\to 1}\left(\frac{ln\left(x\right)}{\arctan \left(1-x\right)}\right)$$
$$=\lim _{x\to 1}\left(\frac{\frac{d}{dx}\left(ln\left(x\right)\right)}{\frac{d}{dx}\left(\arctan \:\left(1-x\right)\right)}\right)$$
$$=\lim _{x\to 1}\left(\frac{\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)}{\left(\frac{-1}{\left(1-x\right)^2+1}\right)}\right)$$
$$=\lim _{x\to 1}\left(\frac{-x^2+2x-2}{x}\right)$$
$$=\left(\frac{-(1)^2+2(1)-2}{(1)}\right)$$
$$=\frac{-1}{1}$$
$$=-1$$

Answer (score 1):

$$
\lim_{x \to {1}} \frac{\ln(x)}{\arctan(1-x)}.
$$
We must make the substitution here $x=(y+1)$, therefore
$$
\lim_{y \to {0}} \frac{\ln(y+1)}{\arctan(-y)}=\lim_{y \to {0}} \frac{\ln(y+1)}{-\arctan(y)}.
$$
I recommend to use here the **Taylor series**:
$$
\ln(1+x)=x-\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{x^3}{3}-....\tag{1}
$$
$$
\arctan(x)=x-\frac{x^3}{3}+\frac{x^5}{5}-....,\quad\text{for }{-1\le{x}\le{1}},x\ne\pm{i}.\tag{2}
$$
Therefore,
$$
\lim_{y \to {0}} \frac{\ln(y+1)}{-\arctan(y)}=\lim_{y \to {0}} \frac{\left(y-\frac{y^2}{2}+\frac{y^3}{3}-....\right)}{-\left(y-\frac{y^3}{3}+\frac{y^5}{5}-....\right)}=
\\
=\lim_{y \to {0}} \frac{y\left(1-\frac{y}{2}+\frac{y^2}{3}-....\right)}{-y\left(1-\frac{y^2}{3}+\frac{y^4}{5}-....\right)}=\lim_{y \to {0}}\frac{1}{-1}=-1.
$$
We will have, that
$$
\lim_{x \to {1}} \frac{\ln(x)}{\arctan(1-x)}=-1.
$$